# ¿Cómo instalo PIP en Windows?

Tags: python, windows, pip

Pip es un remplazo para easy install. ¿Pero debo instalar Pip usando easy install en Windows? ¿Hay una mejor forma?

Comment: asociación: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4750806

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Traducción literal de [How do I install pip on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12476379/5290909)

**Python 2.7.9+ and 3.4+**

Buenas noticias! [Python 3.4](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.4.html) (lanzado en marzo del 2014) y [Python 2.7.9](https://docs.python.org/2/whatsnew/2.7.html#pep-477-backport-ensurepip-pep-453-to-python-2-7) (lanzado en diciembre del 2014) vienen con Pip. Esta es la mejor característica de una release de Python. Hace accesible para todos el total de librerías de la comunidad. Los novatos no están excluidos de usar las librerías de la comunidad con las limitaciones prohibitivas de su configuración. Lanzado con una administrador de paquetes, Python se una a Ruby, Node.js, Haskell, Perl, Go... casi la mayoria de los lenguajes contemporáneos con mayoría de comunidad open-source. Gracias Python.

Por supuesto, eso no significa que el problema de generar paquetes en Python esta resuelto. La experiencia sigue siendo frustrante. Esto fue discutido (en ingles) [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2436731).

Y para aquellos usando  Python 2.7.8 o anterior (la mayor parte de la comunidad), no hay planes para lanzar Pip para ustedes. Instrucciones manuales a continuación.

**Python 2 ≤ 2.7.8 and Python 3 ≤ 3.3**

Python no viene con un administrador de paquetes. Y para hacer las cosas peores, Pip, hasta recientemente, era difícil de instalar.

[Instrucciones oficiales](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/#do-i-need-to-install-pip).

Descargar [get-pip.py](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py), teniendo cuidado de guardarlo como un archivo con extensión .py en lugar de .txt. Luego, ejecutarlo desde la linea de comando:

```
python get-pip.py
```

Posiblemente se necesiten permisos de administrador para hacer esto. 
Si no sabes como, [aquí las instrucciones](https://technet.microsoft.com/es-ar/library/cc947813(v=ws.10).aspx) (en ingles) (Microsoft TechNet).

**Instrucciones alternativas**

La documentación oficial dice que hay que instalar Pip y cada una de sus dependencias desde el origen. Esto es una experiencia tediosa y muy difícil para novatos.

Por suerte, Christoph Gohlke preparo paquetes de instaladores para Windows (.msi) para paquetes populares de Python. Construyo instaladores para todas las versiones de de Python, tanto para 32 como para 64 bits.

Los pasos a seguir son:

1. [Instalar setuptools](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#setuptools)
2. [Instalar pip](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pip)

En el caso probado, esto instalo Pip en `C:\Python27\Scripts\pip.exe`. Encuentra donde fue instalado `pip.exe` en tu computadora, y luego agrega esa carpeta (por ejemplo, `C:\Python27\Scripts`) a la cadena path (inicio/ editar variables de entorno). Con esto, se debería poder correr pip desde la linea de comandos. Ahora se podría probar instalar un paquete:

```
pip install httpie
```

Si todo anduvo bien, esto debería funcionar sin problemas. Abajo se detallan algunos problemas comunes:

**Problemas con proxy**

Si se trabaja en una oficina, es probable que se este atrás de un proxy. Si es así, hay que setear las variables de entorno [http_proxy y https_proxy](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html). La mayoría de las aplicaciones de Python (y otras de software libre) respetan esto.

Ejemplo:

```
http://proxy_url:puerto
http://nombredeusuario:password@proxy_url:port
```

Con mucha mala suerte, si el proxy es del tipo [Microsoft NTLM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NT_LAN_Manager), las aplicaciones de software libre no pueden con él. En ese caso, la única solución es instalar un proxy que se conecte con ese proxy. Intenta con [este](http://cntlm.sourceforge.net/)

**No se puede encontrar vcvarsall.bat**

Los módulos de Python pueden estar escritos en parte en C o C++. Pip trata de compilar desde código fuente. Si no hay un compilar C/C++ configurado e instalado, aparecerá este error.

> Error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat

Se puede arreglar esto [instalando un compilador de C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817869/error-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat) como [MinGW](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MinGW) o [Visual C++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_C%2B%2B#32-bit_versions). O se puede probar con [Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler para Python 2.7](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44266).

Como nota final, siempre es mas fácil fijarse si no hay un paquete de instalación en el [sitio de Christoph](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/).

Answer (score 2):

La solución mejor es usar **"conda"**. Es el modo estándar *de facto* de instalar paquetes en windows.

La tienes en dos versiones: **[anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads)**, una distribución de python completa orientada a usos científicos, y **[miniconda](https://conda.io/miniconda.html)**, una versión reducida a la que se pueden añadir los paquetes que necesites.

*Conda* tiene disponible una gran colección de paquetes ya compilados listos para instalar. Si aún así no encuentras el que necesitas, la instalación incluye también **pip** con el que instalar otros paquetes.

Una recomendación: antes de instalar nada con pip, crea un entorno virtual python donde instalar el módulo que necesites. Intenta no polucionar la instalación principal.